# Using VBA to control the order of elements in an Excel Pivot Table Field List

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am trying to move a Values data field in a Pivot Table from 1st position to 7th position. My current code is taking the last entry in the last position of the Values data field list and putting it into the 7th slot instead. How can I alter my code to fit my needs?

[Field List - Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuYdr.png)

```
Sub Macro7()

   With Sheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Sunday")
    .Orientation = xlDataField
    .Position = 7
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This will do the trick,
just change the  .**Orientation** 

Sub Macro7()

   With Sheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Sunday")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 7
  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Muthu, that just moved the Sunday field into the Rows portion of the Field List. My goal is for it to stay within the Values portion of the Field List, but move the Sunday field to the 7th position.

Comment: you want to move "sunday" only? and don't want to move value's in the pivot field

Comment: I would like to move "Sunday" only. The goal is to reorder the listed screenshot above from "Sunday - Total" to "Monday - Total". Sunday should end up in the 7th slot. I've found a workaround by individually moving each value, but that's going to slow my macros down too much.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with. It deletes all field within the Values section of the Field List. It then adds them back in the correct order. A bit slow, but I haven't found a better way of doing it yet.

```
 Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable1").DataPivotField.Orientation = xlHidden
    Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable1").PivotFields("Mon"), "Monday", xlCount
    Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable1").PivotFields("Tue"), "Tuesday", xlCount
    Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable1").PivotFields("Wed"), "Wednesday", xlCount
    Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable1").PivotFields("Thu"), "Thursday", xlCount
    Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable1").PivotFields("Fri"), "Friday", xlCount
    Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable1").PivotFields("Sat"), "Saturday", xlCount
    Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable1").PivotFields("Sun"), "Sunday", xlCount
    Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable1").PivotFields("Total Hours"), "Total", xlCount
```